# R - Replacing values in a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I have a `data.frame` containing values for `WIND_CHILL`, `DRY_BULB_TEMP` and `WIND_SPEED`. 
When `WIND_SPEED <= 5` then I would like to set `WIND_CHILL = DRY_ BULB TEMP`, because at these speeds the formula for `WIND_CHILL` does not estimate the temperature effectively. `WIND_CHILL` is the 9th column, `DRY_BULB_TEMP` the 4th column and `WIND_SPEED` the 7th column in the `data.frame`. The `data.frame` is called `venue`. I'm telling you guys this so you can understand what I tried, which is:

```
n <- nrow(venue)
for(i in 1:n) {
     if(venue[n,7] <= 5) {
       venue[n,9] <- venue[n,4]
     }
}
```

Any ideas??

Comment: In the future please post a sample of your data so that others can reproduce your error more easily. To address your question, you shouldn't need a `for` loop to do this - I think something like `venue[,9] <- ifelse(venue[,7]<=5, venue[,4], venue[,9])` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide your `data.frame`, I have to do it out of my head :P.

```
venue[venue$WIND_SPEED<=5,"WIND_CHILL"]=venue[venue$WIND_SPEED<=5,"DRY_BULB_TEMP"]
```

or:

```
venue[venue$WIND_SPEED<=5,9]=venue[venue$WIND_SPEED<=5,4]
```

Comment: Your `WIND_CHILL` and `DRY_BULB_TEMP` should be either `"WIND_CHILL"` and `"DRY_BULB_TEMP"` or `venue$WIND_CHILL` and `venue$DRY_BULB_TEMP` when used inside of `venue`. Other than that, your approach looks correct.

Comment: ooops that and a typo

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have access to your data set, so I had to come up with a simple example.

```
x1<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=10)
x2<-rep(0,100)
x3<-rep(1,100)

df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

summary(df$x2)

#overwrite x2 for values of x1 less than 3 
df$x2[ which(df$x1 < 3) ] <- 1

summary(df$x2)

summary(df$x3)
#overwrite x3 for values of x1 >= 3
df$x3[ which(df$x1 >= 3) ] <- 0

summary(df$x3)
```

You'll notice that we have a data frame with 3 variables. x1 is a random variable, and x2 and x3 are nominalizations of x1 (x2 should be 1 if x1 < 3 and x3 should be 0 if x1 >= 3). When I run this, you'll notice that the use of the which statement helps to selectively overwrite values because it returns the indices that need to be overwritten.

```
> x1<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=10)
> x2<-rep(0,100)
> x3<-rep(1,100)
> 
> df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
> 
> summary(df$x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       0       0       0       0       0 
> 
> #overwrite x2 for values of x1 less than 3 
> df$x2[ which(df$x1 < 3) ] <- 1
> 
> summary(df$x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    0.00    1.00    0.58    1.00    1.00 
> 
> summary(df$x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1       1 
> #overwrite x3 for values of x1 >= 3
> df$x3[ which(df$x1 >= 3) ] <- 1
> 
> summary(df$x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1       1 
> x1<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=10)
> x2<-rep(0,100)
> x3<-rep(1,100)
> 
> df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
> 
> summary(df$x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       0       0       0       0       0 
> 
> #overwrite x2 for values of x1 less than 3 
> df$x2[ which(df$x1 < 3) ] <- 1
> 
> summary(df$x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    0.00    1.00    0.63    1.00    1.00 
> 
> summary(df$x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1       1 
> #overwrite x3 for values of x1 >= 3
> df$x3[ which(df$x1 >= 3) ] <- 0
> 
> summary(df$x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    0.00    1.00    0.63    1.00    1.00
```